# 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. but my node is working

Tags: reactjs, npm, server, localhost, version

In the react file when Iam trying to start the server, (npm start) it is showing
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
But my node and nvm version is working fine. What is the solution?

I tried npm start command to start react project
And Iam expecting to start server but it's not

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Laptop/Pc maybe it will solve the issue or you can use npm i it will install all the required dependencies which are left and after npm i you can use npm start

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).